# How to call ajax from Excel JS API

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, office-js, office-addins, exceljs

I am new to `Office.js API`. I am trying to develop `Web Add-In for Excel` and I need to get data from `WebAPI` for this I am trying to use `ajax` but its not working

Here is very simple Ajax code

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:61721/api/values",
        type: "GET",
        dataType:"JSONP",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#div1").html(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error:function(error){}
    });
```

**Update**

Is there any alternative way other than `Ajax` in `Office.js` through which we can get data from `Web API`?

Comment: Would this answer your question: [Send POST AJAX request from Office Add-In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45308473/send-post-ajax-request-from-office-add-in/45308930#45308930)

Answer (score 0):

From the client, AJAX requests must be send to SSL URIs and those URIs must be declared in `AppDomain` list of the app manifest. Please refer to: [Send POST AJAX request from Office Add-In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45308473/send-post-ajax-request-from-office-add-in/45308930#45308930).

In the same time, if your app has server side portion of code, you may send direct request to any Web API from there. Nobody limit you in technology (REST, microservices, etc.) and nobody check your connection is secure, when using 3rd party resources from your server.

Comment: You might also find the following useful:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2013/06/10/create-a-web-service-for-an-app-for-office-using-the-asp-net-web-api/